# Google Sheets Displaying cell data in sidebar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet that I'm using as a timesheet. I'd like to use the sidebar to report contents of cells. In addition to the main timesheet, I have a sheet that is dedicated to keeping track of total hours and overtime.

I'm looking for a way to display cell values from my tracking sheet in the sidebar, and have it update values every time the spreadsheet is edited.

Despite looking for several days, I either can't find, or can't grasp how it's done.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Create an `onEdit()` simple trigger function that runs every time a cell is edited.  The sidebar will probably need to be re-displayed every time there is an edit that you want updated in the sidebar.  I don't know of anyway to pass data to the sidebar without re-displaying it.  I hope I'm wrong.  I haven't researched it, but I can't think how that would be done.  You could update the spreadsheet from the sidebar with no problem.  But I don't know how you'd update the sidebar from the spreadsheet without re-displaying the sidebar.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, life issues and all.

I'm aware of the onEdit() stuff, and how to assign OnEdit triggers to individual functions, but it's more of an issue of variable displaying and sidebar updating.

Thanks for your response though. I appreciate your time.